# JavaScript removeChild does not remove div element

Tags: javascript, dom

I am facing a problem with JavaScript removeChild function and unfortunately its the first time I can't find what's wrong on the forum. Here is the scenario:
-Create div elements with a for loop and put the word test in it
-When one of those div is clicked, append to it the div element stored in a Foo object
-If the div from Foo object is clicked, remove it from DOM

Here is the code I use. Tried in IE and FF. No error is displayed, removeChild SEEMS to work ok, BUT the foo div is never removed. Hopefully someone can help me find out why that doesn't work.

```
function Foo() {
 this.container = document.createElement("div");
 this.container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("foo"));

 this.container.onclick = function() {  
  // in the function'this' refers to the clicked element, i.e. container
  console.log(this.parentNode); // the clicked div has a parent
  console.log(this.parentNode.removeChild(this)); // the div is removed from DOM
  console.log(this.parentNode); // null, the clicked div has no more parent but...
  // foo is STILL DISPLAYED ?!
 }
}

var foo = new Foo();

function Test() {
 // create 3 div with the word test inside
 for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
  var t = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  t.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test"));
  // when test div is clicked, append to it the container (a div element) from object foo
  // due to the for loop we need a closure for t
  t.onclick = function(t){ return function() {
   t.appendChild(foo.container); // here it works great and t is moved to the clicked test div
  }; }(t);
 }
}

new Test();
```

Many thanks for taking the time to investigate my issue

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle out of this ?

Comment: Are you sure the `click` event is occurring on the `div`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question would be improved by not including all the stuff that happens before the `removeChild` statement. Please simplify.

Comment: @isherwood I found it quite useful in understanding the context of the problem and what is trying to be achieved...

Comment: Fair enough. Some of us would like to see the HTML, though.

Comment: @isherwood there is no HTML other than a `<body>` tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the container with the word `foo` in it, you also click the `t` div with the word `test` in it. Which has a click handler that does append your `foo.container` back to the element from which your `foo.container.onclick` handler has just removed it.

**Quick fix**: After the container has handled the `click` event, it stops propagation of the event to elements higher in the DOM tree:

```
 …
 this.container.onclick = function(e) {  
  // in the function'this' refers to the clicked element, i.e. container
  console.log(this.parentNode); // the clicked div has a parent
  console.log(this.parentNode.removeChild(this)); // the div is removed from DOM
  console.log(this.parentNode); // null, the clicked div has no more parent

  e.stopPropagation();
  // foo is NO MORE DISPLAYED
 }
 …
```

**Advanced fix**: Don't attach the handler that adds `foo` to the `t` element, but only to the `test` word. You will need an extra element for that, though:

```
  …
  var t = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  var s = t.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
  s.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test"));
  // when test div is clicked, append to it the container (a div element) from object foo
  // due to the for loop we need a closure for t
  s.onclick = function(s){ return function() {
   s.appendChild(foo.container); // here it works great and t is moved to the clicked test div
  }; }(s);
  …
```

A variant of this would be to not append the `foo.container` to `t` itself, but as a sibling or so.

Comment: Oh I see that was tricky. Good catch thank you so much. Now it works all fine.

Answer (score 0):

you added onclick event to the container, so the correct code would be:

```
function Foo() {
this.container = document.createElement("div");
this.container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("foofoofoooooo"));

this.container.onclick = function() {
this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
 }
 }

 var foo = new Foo();

 function Test() {
 // create 3 div with the word test inside
 for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
  var t = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            t.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test"));
  // when test div is clicked, append to it the container (a div element) from object foo
  // due to the for loop we need a closure for t
      t.onclick = function(t){ return function()      {
   t.appendChild(foo.container); // here     it works great and t is moved to the     clicked test div
  }; }(t);
 }
}

 new Test();
```

I tested and it works!

Comment: Bergi was more precise, infact you append and remove the node each time